# Preserve Exif/Image Properties

Tags: vb.net, image, image-processing

In a web app, users can upload images, which save on the server. It creates thumbnails of the image on the back end with the following code, but all exif data of the image is lost.

I want to preserve the exif data from the original image all throughout the process, and have it included in the final stream. I can read the exif properties from the image, but can't get it to preserve when saving.

To clarify, I am not trying to read, parse, or do anything specific to the metadata itself, I just want to preserve it exactly as it was in the original image during image processing.

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    'prepare image
    Dim imgFullSize As System.Drawing.Image

    'attempt to get the image       
    Dim sInputURL As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("IptFl"))
    If InStr(sInputURL, "http://") > 0 Or InStr(sInputURL, "https://") Then

        'from web url
        Dim imgWebRequest As System.Net.WebRequest
        Dim imgWebResponse As System.Net.WebResponse
        imgWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sInputURL)
        imgWebResponse = imgWebRequest.GetResponse()
        imgFullSize = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgWebResponse.GetResponseStream())

    Else

        'from file
        imgFullSize = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(sInputURL))

    End If



'   Dim props As PropertyItem() = imgFullSize.PropertyItems
'   For Each prop As PropertyItem In props
'       Response.Write(prop.Id.ToString() & "<br />")
'   Next




    'determine type
    Dim sFileExtension As String = "png"
    If Left(Right(sInputURL, 4), 1) = "." Then sFileExtension = Right(sInputURL, 3) 'for jpg, gif, etc
    If Left(Right(sInputURL, 5), 1) = "." Then sFileExtension = Right(sInputURL, 4) 'for tiff, jpeg, etc


    Dim jpgEncoder As ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim gifEncoder As ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Gif)
    Dim pngEncoder As ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Png)


    'set the quality
    Dim myEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality
    Dim myEncoderParams As New EncoderParameters(1)
    Dim myEncoderQuality As New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, CType(100L, Int32))
    myEncoderParams.Param(0) = myEncoderQuality


    'save img to memory stream
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    Select Case sFileExtension
        Case "jpg" : imgFullSize.Save(ms, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParams)
        Case "png", "gif" : imgFullSize.Save(ms, pngEncoder, myEncoderParams)
        Case Else : imgFullSize.Save(ms, pngEncoder, myEncoderParams)
    End Select


    'output the memory stream
    Response.ContentType = "image/" & sFileExtension
    ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)

    '---> when I save the above image and look at the exif, it doesn't exist

End Sub


Private Function GetEncoder(ByVal format As ImageFormat) As ImageCodecInfo
    Dim codecs As ImageCodecInfo() = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()
    Dim codec As ImageCodecInfo
    For Each codec In codecs
        If codec.FormatID = format.Guid Then Return codec
    Next codec
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this did the trick.  Basically I had to loop through the source image properties, and for each, set the property in the new image.

```
        'retrieve relative path to image
        Dim sSrc As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("IptFl"))


        'prepare image
        Dim oImg As System.Drawing.Image


        'attempt to get the image, either from web or local file
        If InStr(sSrc, "http://") > 0 Or InStr(sSrc, "https://") Then
            Dim oRequest As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sSrc)
            Dim oResponse As System.Net.WebResponse = oRequest.GetResponse()        
            oImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(oResponse.GetResponseStream())
            oResponse.Close()
        Else
            oImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(sSrc))
        End If

        'discard if image file not found
        If oImg Is Nothing Then Response.End()

        Dim sFileExt As String = Split(sSrc, ".")(UBound(Split(sSrc, ".")))


        Dim oCanvas As System.Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(oImg.Width, oImg.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555)

        For Each pi As PropertyItem In oImg.PropertyItems
            oCanvas.SetPropertyItem(pi)
        Next

        Dim oGraphic As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(oCanvas)
        oGraphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Default
        oGraphic.DrawImage(oImg, 0, 0, oImg.Width, oImg.Height)
        Dim oStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        oCanvas.Save(oStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        Response.ContentType = "image/" & sFileExt

        'output the memory stream
        oStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
        Response.End()
```